# What's the proper way to load a UITableView with 10,000+ rows from a server?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, lazy-loading

I've got 10,000+ items on a server. What is the proper lazy loading code pattern to fill these items into a `UITableView` and its cells? Each custom cell would contain multiple pieces of information, like title, price, description, image, etc.

Questions:

1. Should I call the server to get a full count of items before downloading any additional data, so I can make the `UITableView` the proper size?
2. Should I load each one individually as a call to the server in the background? Or should I load them in chunks of 20 or 50 or whatever so I don't have to hit the server so often?
3. I know how to do this with images already... I just use the SDWebImage library and it works great. Is there a simple library or way to do this for text as well?
4. What technique is best used to store/release as needed this data in memory once it's been downloaded? (maybe a library from question #3 will take care of the memory management from me, like SDWebImage does?)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty loaded question, but I'd look into infinite scrolling.

Edit: idk how to make lists clearly, so bare the format....

1. Basically load `x` amount, and keep loading that amount as one scrolls down. If at some point you end up loading less than your `x` amount, then that should imply that you've loaded your last chunk of data.

   2. You should definitely NOT load 1 at a time. That is the worst possible idea. Load however many seem right. Like for a feed, you maybe want to load the first 30 posts, then load 30 more when they scroll down far enough, etc.
   3. Images and text are differently. Just load your text in batches. If there are images in need, get the url of the image from the data, then use SDWebImage to fetch the image.
   4. UITableView will take care of this for you.

Comment: Thanks, make sense. Can you give me a bit more details about what you mean by #1? Don't you need to tell the UITableView how many rows it has/needs before you start loading data into it?

Comment: @EthanAllen Your UITableView will know how many rows it currently has because you tell it that data. That is extremely important. But, it doesn't need to know anything about data it'll have in the future. If you load your data into an array, you'll just tell your UITableView that its number of rows is the current length of the array. Every time you load more data, you'll end up calling something like reloadData() on your UITableView, which will recalculate everything with your new data.

Comment: Ah ok makes sense! Didn't even think of it that way. Thank you.